# SWT Composite with movable Controls (drag and drop)

Tags: jakarta-ee, drag-and-drop, swt

I am trying to implement a `DragAndDrop` capability on a `ScrolledForm` with several expandable `Sections`. I should be able to move sections around in the form, reordering them.

After a bit (a lot) of research, I've learned that my best chance is to define my own custom Transfer for the `DragSource` and `DropTarget`.

All in all, how can you move around a `Control` in a `Composite`?

**Update:**

Alright, so. My `Sections` no longer need to be expandable. They are 'solid' sections of different sizes. This eases my problem but doesn't solve it.

I've tried variations of `Drag and Drop`, with and without a`Transfer`. The all-mighty Internet didn't think about implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have to implement `DragSource` and `DropTarget`. When you drag a `control` , you could actually change `cursor` to image of the actual control ( Look at `Control.print(GC)` method to create `Image`). All you need to do once the drop is finished is change bounds of the `Control`.`(Control.setBounds (int x, int y, int width, int height) )`

As you want to lay out your `Controls` in free form, I would suggest you to restrict to set any `Layout` on the form and you have to manually calculate and set bounds on each child `Control`.

Comment: My sections do not implement `Control` in any way. So it's kinda hard to set the bounds. Should I extend `Composite` on the section components?

Comment: if you are using org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section, then it extends Control. you can set bounds on it.

Comment: Did a blog post on this, with source code. http://georgiangrec.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/swt-composite-drag-and-drop/